# How to sum up all values in a row where the column contains a specific string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe of categories of venues in each neighbourhood. It looks like:

[image]

The values in each row represent the no. of each venue in the specific neighbourhood.

I want to find out the total number of restaurants in each neighbourhood. To do so, I know I have to sum up the values in a row where the column contains the string "Restaurant".

I've tried using `str.contains` function but that sums up True cases - how many times a column containing the string `restaurant` has a value `>0` in that row. But instead, what I'd like is, to sum up, the total no. of restaurants in the neighbourhood instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [**`pd.Index.str.contains`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.str.html#pandas-index-str)  with [**`df.loc`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) here.

```
df['sum_rest'] = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('Restaurant')].sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"restaurant_a": [1,2,3], "shop": [2,3,4], "restaurant_b": [4,5,6]})
df["sum_rest"] = df[[x for x in df.columns if "restaurant" in x]].sum(axis = "columns")
df
```

The result is:

```
   restaurant_a  shop  restaurant_b  sum_rest
0             1     2             4         5
1             2     3             5         7
2             3     4             6         9
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a list of columns containing "Restaurant" :

```
lr = ["Afgan Restaurant", "American Restaurant", "Argentinian Restaurant"]
```

Then parse the result and put it in a column :

```
df["sum_restaurant"] = df.loc[:, columns=lr].apply(lambda row : np.sum(row.to_numpy()))
```